# get numpy array of matplotlib tricontourf

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, contour

I had x,y,height vars to build a contour in python.
I created a Triangulation grid using

x,y,height and traing are numpy arrays

```
tri = Tri.Triangulation(x, y, triang)
```

then i did a contour using tricontourf

```
tricontourf(tri,height)
```

how can i get the output of the tricontourf into a numpy array. I can display the image using pyplot but I dont want to.

when I tried this:

```
triout = tricontourf(tri,height)
print triout
```

I got:

```
<matplotlib.tri.tricontour.TriContourSet instance at 0xa9ab66c>
```

I need to get the image data and if I could get numpy array its easy for me.

Is it possible to do this?

if its not possible can I do what tricontourf does without matplotlib in python?

Comment: Try `print dir(triout)` to see what's available in the object. For instance, there's a `get_array` method that will give you an array, but I don't know if it's the array you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this :

```
cs = tricontourf(tri,height)
for collection in cs.collections:
    for path in collection.get_paths():
        print path.to_polygons()
```

as I learned on: 
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/367

(it is better to use `path.to_polygons()` )